# Zeppelin 6.5 + Apache Kafka connector for Structured Streaming 2.0.2

Tags: streaming, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-2.0, apache-kafka-connect, databricks

I'm trying to run a zeppelin notebook that contains spark's Structured Streaming example with Kafka connector.

```
>kafka is up and running on localhost port 9092 

>from zeppelin notebook, sc.version returns String = 2.0.2
```

**Here is my environment:**

```
kafka: kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0

zeppelin: zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all

spark: spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7
```

**Here is the code in my zeppelin notebook:**

```
import org.apache.enter code herespark.sql.functions.{explode, split}


// Setup connection to Kafka val kafka = spark.readStream  
.format("kafka")   
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")   
// comma separated list of broker:host  
.option("subscribe", "twitter")    
// comma separated list of topics 
.option("startingOffsets", "latest") 
// read data from the end of the stream   .load()
```

**Here is the error I'm getting when I run the notebook:**

> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, split}
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka.
>   Please find packages at
>   https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Third+Party+Projects
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:148)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:218)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:124)
>   ... 86 elided Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   kafka.DefaultSource   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
>   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)

Any help advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thnx

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource indicates you are missing this class from your class path. What does your class path look like and does it include a jar with this kafka.DefaultStore class?

Comment: The pain of my existence in the last couple weeks. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have figured this out already but putting in the answer for others, you have to add the following to zeppelin-env.sh.j2

```
SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0
```

along with potentially other dependencies if you are using the kafka client:

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.1.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.10.0.1,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has been tested in zeppelin version 0.10.1.

You need to add dependencies of your code. It can be done with zeppelin UI. Go to Interpreter panel (http://localhost:8080/#/interpreter) and in *spark* section, under *Dependencies* you can add artifact of each dependency. If by adding *spark-sql-kafka* you ran into other dependency issues, add all packages the spark-sql-kafka needs. You can find them in *Compile Dependencies* section of it's maven repository.

I'm working with spark version 3.0.0 and scala version 2.12 and I was trying to integrate spark with kafka. I managed to get passed this issue by adding all the bellow artifacts:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0
    
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0   

org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.12:3.3.0  

org.apache.spark:spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 

org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.0
```